# Remove rows of NA values, if they occur for a specific time range in loop to slow?

Tags: r, conditional-statements, na, posixct

I am new to R so I am sorry if I ask an obvious question. I searched know for a week and didn't manage to find a solution.

I have a dataframe with many columns and rows. 
Now I want to remove all rows if:

Column A has in a timerange of e.g. 8 hours only NA values 
Then delete all rows which are in this range.

Background: Originally I wanted to remove rows that occured on weekends, because this are not working days/hours. But I have also not working days/hours during the week which occur "randomly". So I want just the data where the device was actually working. And my table is not messed up because of this "missing values" which are not real missing values.

The only piece of code I found is the following:

```
df[-which(rowMeans(is.na(df)) > 0,3), ]
```

I think there is a possibility to modify this code to my conditions, but I don't have a clue.
At the moment it looks just every row and decides if there are more than 30% of NA. But that is not sufficient, because I have data of several weeks and I cannot say before how often and in which time range NA's show up.

Here an example:

```
df <- data.frame(DateTime = c('2019-05-31 08:23:00', '2019-05-31 09:46:00', '2019-05-31 10:00:00', '2019-05-31 11:07:00', '2019-05-31 11:10:00','2019-05-31 11:56:00', '2019-05-31 12:06:00', '2019-05-31 12:56:00', '2019-05-31 14:16:00', '2019-05-31 15:45:00', '2019-05-31 16:03:00', '2019-05-31 17:05:00', '2019-05-31 18:00:00', '2019-05-31 19:30:00', '2019-05-31 20:01:00'),
             A=c(NA, 1, 2, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA ),
             B = c(NA, 2.4, 3, 5, NA, NA, 2.5, NA, NA, 2.6, NA, NA, NA, 1, 2)) 


      DateTime  A   B
1  2019-05-31 08:23:00 NA  NA
2  2019-05-31 09:46:00  1 2.4
3  2019-05-31 10:00:00  2 3.0
4  2019-05-31 11:07:00 NA 5.0
5  2019-05-31 11:10:00 NA  NA
6  2019-05-31 11:56:00 NA  NA
7  2019-05-31 12:06:00 NA 2.5
8  2019-05-31 12:56:00 NA  NA
9  2019-05-31 14:16:00 NA  NA
10 2019-05-31 15:45:00 NA 2.6
11 2019-05-31 16:03:00 NA  NA
12 2019-05-31 17:05:00 NA  NA
13 2019-05-31 18:00:00 NA  NA
14 2019-05-31 19:30:00 NA 1.0
15 2019-05-31 20:01:00 NA 2.0
```

Additionally there is to say that I don't have a fix amount of rows corresponding to the time range. The NA value can occur in the defined 8 hour time range 8,76 or 10 times.

That's how I want it to look like:

```
DateTime             A   B
1  2019-05-31 08:23:00 NA  NA
2  2019-05-31 09:46:00  1 2.4
3  2019-05-31 10:00:00  2  NA
4  2019-05-31 20:01:00  1 2.0
```

I hope I described my problem properly and someone is able to help me out.

Thanks a lot!

UPDATE: I find a loop solution, but its painfully slow. Can someone propose maybe something faster. For an amount of 400k rows the loop takes 1 hour...therefore every day the amount of rows increases it is not the solution to run with the loop.

Here the code:
    A <- AggregatedTable$CycleTimer1
    D <- AggregatedTable$DateTime

```
startIndex = -1

for(i in 1:nrow(AggregatedTable))                    
{ 
  if (is.na(A[i]))                      
  {
    if (startIndex == -1)
    {
      startIndex = i;
    }
  }
  else 
  {         
    if (startIndex != -1)
    {
      lastIndex = i - 1
      if((difftime(D[lastIndex], D[startIndex]) >= 8)) 
      {    
        AggregatedTable <- AggregatedTable[-(startIndex:lastIndex), , drop = FALSE]
      } 
      startIndex = -1
    }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

We create a grouping variable based on the occurrence of `NA` with `rleid` and `filter` based on the number of rows

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
df %>% 
   group_by(grp = rleid(is.na(A))) %>%
   filter(!(n() >= 8 & all(is.na(A)))) %>%
   ungroup %>%
   select(-grp)
# A tibble: 5 x 3
#  DateTime                A     B
#  <fct>               <dbl> <dbl>
#1 2019-05-31 08:23:00    NA  NA  
#2 2019-05-31 09:46:00     1   2.4
#3 2019-05-31 10:00:00     2  NA  
#4 2019-05-31 11:07:00     3  NA  
#5 2019-05-31 20:01:00     1   2
```

Comment: I am impressed how fast I got an answer. Thanks @akrun.
But with this way we don't take into account the time just the number of rows. In my case the 8 hours don't correspond to the amount of rows because I have irregular frequency. So what will be the case, if I have in some cases 18 rows in this 8 hours and in an other case 50 rows in this 8 hours?

Comment: @Irina3891 I thought your 'DateTime' is `arrange`d. If it is not arranged, then you may need to `arrange` first `df %>% arrange(ymd_hms(DateTime)) %>%`  from `lubridate`

Comment: @Irina3891  Do you have data with difference in time more than 1 hour (even after arranged) and then you want to skip those?  Can you please update your post with that kind of an example

Comment: The data is ordered. But I don't have the same frequency over time. The data is saved randomly. So there is no on value per hour but sometime 10 values/rows in on hour and sometime just 3 values/rows. So it is not possible to say 1 hour is 1 NA value.

Comment: I updated the example data. Hopefully it's a little bit clearer now?

Comment: @Irina3891  I couldn't understand the 8 hour rule here `df %>% mutate(DateTime = ymd_hms(DateTime)) %>% arrange(DateTime) %>%  group_by(grp = rleid(is.na(A)), grp2 = cut(DateTime, '8 hour'))`  If I do the grouping based on this,  the number of NA elements in the group would decrease from 8 to 7 and for the last group 5.  The logic seems to be a bit off `df %>% mutate(DateTime = ymd_hms(DateTime)) %>% arrange(DateTime) %>%  group_by(grp = rleid(is.na(A)), grp2 = cut(DateTime, '8 hour')) %>% summarise(n = sum(is.na(A)))`

Comment: so basically you make a group with 8 hours from the first row at 08:23:00 until the 10th row at 15:45:00.
In my case the 8 hours relate to the duration of NA values. So from 4th row 11:07:00 for at least 8 hours. That would mean at least until 19:07:00. So the code should be able to "detect" when NA values start and last for at least 8 hours. 
I thought about something like:

Comment: @ akrun I thought about something like: 
Check if NA -> save Datetime -> check next row -> if NA -> save Datetime-> check if duration of first Datetime and second value is at least 8 hours -> if not check next row -> if NA ... I know it might be very slow but that is the only Idea I could think of.

Comment: @ akrun: I tried a loop. But my counter fails to count the amount of NA's for the period of the 8 hours...maybe you can give it a look?
    A <- df$A
    D <- df$DateTime

    for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
      if(is.na(A[i])){
        b = as.numeric(i)  #counter
while(is.na(A[i+1] & i< nrow(df))){
      i=i+1}
    if(as.numeric(difftime(D[i], D[b])) > 8){
      df[-(b:i), , drop = FALSE]}
    i = b   #so i is also numeric for difference calculation etc.
  }}